# Is ASP.NET still worth learning or is it being replaced by frameworks like JQuery

Tags: asp.net

We have been using ASP.NET for a big project for > 5 years.
Recently, we find that JavaScript is a preferred way of rendering data on the page.
So I would like to ask if others are also moving in the direction of JavaScript / WebServices / JSON and thus ASP.NET is becoming irrelevant ?

Also, does anybody ever use ASP.NET Server Controls or is it completely obsolete by now ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you taken the time to read up on each technology? You'll quickly learn that ASP.Net and jQuery are independent of eachother...

Comment: @Arief I believe the project is older than 5 years not his experience on it.

Comment: What can ASP.NET do that JQuery + WebServices + JSON can not ?

Comment: How about less sarcasm and more substance ?

Comment: @David Read the replays, they very good answers, but its seems that you have more to understand - this is not sarcasm, is with love.

Comment: Look, To bring data to the client: Web Services -> JSON -> JQuery;
Send data back to the server: JQuery Ajax -> Web Services -> Update display with JQuery again.

No ASP.NET involved.
What's the problem with that ?

Comment: @David The problem is that is too complicate, what about smaller easy thinks, like show a simple page.

Answer (score 2):

First of all ASP.NET is server side framework and JavaScript is client side language. They work TOGETHER not one instead of the other.

How you build your UI depends on what you want to achieve. I personally wouldn't build a UI with JS though some people do it. I would generate some HTML (via server controls) on the server and send it to the client via a service or a handler.

Finally not every website needs to be application like. Sites like SO, Wikipedia, etc. are not only better as server pages that you can refresh and link to but also need to work that way for SEO reasons.

BTW in my opinion the Update Panels are remarkable AJAX technology. They've got bad reputation because they were used for everything AJAX even when they were not appropriate but there are many cases (for example ajaxifying a grid with paging and sorting) where they are a beautiful solution.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is definitely still relevant.

jQuery is a client library. You still need a way to store and deliver the data to the client from the server. That's where ASP.NET comes in.

Comment: We use WebServices (ASMX) and JSON for that.

Comment: @David asmx web services are still ASP.NET

Comment: @Stilgar David Probably meant "ASP .NET WebForms". Lots of people don't make that distinction.

Comment: The irony is that the asmx version of the web services is far more "dead" than Web Forms :)